# Big-O notation and integration

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Question: For fixed $T$, prove the following $$\int_{1/2}^{2} \zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma=\mathcal{O}(T^{1/4+\epsilon}) \tag{*}$$
where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

My Idea:  $$\int_{1/2}^{2} \zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma=\int_{1/2}^{1}\zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma+\int_{1}^{2}\zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma\tag{1}$$
We know that for $s=\sigma+it$, $$\zeta(s)=\mathcal{O}(\log(t)), \ \ \ \sigma\geq 1\tag{2}$$

The Phragmen-Lindelof convexity principle implies that,

$$\zeta(s)=\mathcal{O}(t^{(1-\sigma)/2}\log(t))\text{, uniformly in}\ \ 0\leq\sigma\leq 1\tag{3}$$
So using equation $(3)$ and $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get
$$\int_{1/2}^{2} \zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma=\int_{1/2}^{1}\mathcal{O}(T^{(1-\sigma)/2}\log(T))d\sigma+\int_{1}^{2}\mathcal{O}(\log(T))d\sigma\tag{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow\int_{1/2}^{2} \zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma=\int_{1/2}^{1}\mathcal{O}(T^{(1-\sigma)/2}\log(T))d\sigma+\mathcal{O}(\log(T))\tag{5}$$
$$\Rightarrow\int_{1/2}^{2} \zeta(\sigma+iT)d\sigma=2(T^{1/4}-1)+\mathcal{O}(\log(T))\tag{6}$$
How do we prove equation $(*)$.
Please guide me.

Comment: Note that $2 (T^{1/4} - 1) + \mathcal{O}(\log T) = \mathcal{O}(T^{1/4 + \epsilon})$.

Comment: @prets Thank you. I cannot see it directly. Please show the calculation involved

Comment: @prets What is $\epsilon$ here?

Comment: Here $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary. Every term in the left-hand side is dominated by $T^{1/4 + \epsilon}$, so the right-hand side is just a simplification.

Comment: @prets Sorry but still I cannot follow. Please help me.

Comment: @prets How is $O(\log T)$ dominated by $O(T^{1/4+\epsilon})$?

Comment: Logarithms grow very slowly; indeed $\log T = O(T^{\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. One way to check this is by studying the limit of $(\log T)/T^\epsilon$, for example using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @prets Thank you.

Comment: Quite sure that you need a bound on $\Re(s)=0$ (using the functional equation) to apply Phragmen-Lindelof.

Comment: @reuns Thank you. So how do we integrate using Big O notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\log T$ grows slower than $T^\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ (use e.g. L'Hôpital's rule to verify this), it follows that
$$ 2 (T^{1/4} - 1) + \mathcal{O}(\log T) = \mathcal{O}(T^{1/4 + \epsilon}) $$
because every term in the left-hand side is dominated by $T^{1/4 + \epsilon}$.
In particular, the idea is that since for $T$ large enough we have
$$
\log T \leq T^\epsilon \leq T^{1/4 + \epsilon},
$$
it follows that anything of size $\mathcal{O}(\log T)$ is dominated by something of size $\mathcal{O}(T^{1/4 + \epsilon})$.

Comment: But then we have $$ 2 (T^{1/4} - 1) + \mathcal{O}(\log T) =\mathcal{O}(T^{1/4})+ \mathcal{O}(T^{\epsilon}) $$ How to conclude?

Comment: The last term in the right-hand side is definitely also $\mathcal{O}(T^{1/4 + \epsilon})$, right? Since $1/4 + \epsilon > \epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry I could think that : Is it true that if $T^\epsilon<T^{1/4+\epsilon}$ then  $O(T^\epsilon)=O(T^{1/4+\epsilon})$?

Comment: Please reply. I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Well it's sort of an abuse of notation since we are definitely not saying that the class of "$T^\epsilon$-size" is the same as the class of "$T^{1/4+\epsilon}-size"$ functions, but anything in the former is dominated by something in the latter. So $T^\epsilon = O(T^{1/4+\epsilon})$.

Comment: Did you mean that $O(T^\epsilon)=O(T^{1/4+\epsilon})$?

Comment: Sort of yes and no. It's a notation issue, you have to be careful manipulating big O sometimes, because the equality sign in there is definitely not symmetric. But yes, the manipulation to get the final answer here is fine.

Comment: Please include these manipulations in your answer. I am unable to write it formally.

Comment: I've added something to that effect. What counts as formally for your purposes might depend on context...

Comment: Please suggest me some material to study big O notation.

Comment: I don't know of any reference specifically about this. Most introductory analytic number theory texts will probably have a bit of a discussion on the topic somewhere (presumably before they discuss the $\zeta(s) = O(\log t)$, $\sigma \geq 1$ bound you're using?). But I guess [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum) on the Wikipedia page motivates the manipulation I'm doing, if you want. (But in general, think about the definition and you'll be fine.)